# Copying plugins to base wordpress image, Plugins folders are visible in cmd but not visible in volume mount

Tags: wordpress, image, docker, plugins

Copy plugins to wordpress base image. Plugins folders are visible in cmd [CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snZe3.png) using command docker run -it --rm arslanliaqat/testwordpressimage sh but not visible in volume mounted [Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE6Pj.png). I have attached the screenshot of cmd commands and folder as well.

Dockerfile

```
FROM wordpress:php7.1-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY plugins/wordpress-seo/ /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/
COPY plugins/wp-super-cache/ /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/

EXPOSE 80
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    db:
        image: 'mysql:5.7'
        volumes:
            - './dbdata:/var/lib/mysql'
        restart: always
        environment:
            #PMA_HOST: db
            #PMA_PORT: 3000   
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
            MYSQL_USER: wordpress
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress 

    wordpress:
        depends_on:
            - db
        image: 'arslanliaqat/testwordpressimage:latest'
        #image: 'wordpress:latest'
        volumes:
            #- './wordpress/:/var/www/html/'
            - './Wordpress:/var/www/html'
            #- './wordpress:/var/www/html'
            #- './wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/:/wp-content/wordpress-seo/'
            #- './wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/:/wp-content/wp-super-cache/'
            # - './plugins/wordpress-seo/:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/'
            # - './plugins/wp-super-cache/:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/'
            - './docker/wordpress/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini:ro'
        ports:
            - '8000:80'
        restart: always
        environment:
            WP_LOCALE: en_US
            WORDPRESS_LOCALE: en_US
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: 'db:3306'
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
            WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: wp_
            WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
            WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
            working_dir: /var/www/html

volumes:
    db_data: 
    wordpress:
```

Answer (score 0):

> Bind mounts have been around since the early days of Docker. Bind mounts have limited functionality compared to volumes. When you use a bind mount, a file or directory on the host machine is mounted into a container.

That means: when you define `- './Wordpress:/var/www/html'` in compose, the directory `/var/www/html` in container will be override by the directory `./Wordpress` on host. So you can just see the contents of your hosts.

But for [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snZe3.png), you did not use bind mount volume, so your things in container not override by host directory.

Detail refers to [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

Comment: - './Wordpress:/var/www/html' :  this line means it will create a new wordpress directory on the host system and copy all the content from the image "/var/www/html" to host directory "wordpress". Right?

Comment: No, if your host already has `./Wordpress`, it will be mount into the containers, and then the contents of `/var/www/html` in container just same as the one in host's `./Wordpress`. If your host do not have the folder `./Wordpress`, then, will create an empty folder for you, then the `/var/www/html` in your container will be empty.

Comment: Without creating new image and pushing it to docker hub, my wordpress installation is showing these two plugins installed. what do you suggest me to do then.

Comment: Don't separate your `wordpress code` & `plugin` to different parts. I mean either in dockerfile, copy all `wordpress code` & `plugin` together. Or just put your `wordpress code` & `plugin` all on the folder of `./Wordpress` on the host, then mount to container in compose.